# What is the difference between Type.IsPublic and Type.IsVisible

Tags: c#, reflection, clr

In C# the `Type` class instances have a lot of properties. Two of them are `IsPublic` and `IsVisible`:

- [Type.IsPublic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispublic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Gets a value indicating whether the Type is declared public.
- [Type.IsVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) - Gets a value indicating whether the Type can be accessed by code outside the assembly.

As far as I know all public members can be accessed outside of the assembly and all others cannot. Two exceptions I can think of are the `[InternalsVisibleTo:]` assembly attribute and `protected` modifier for members.

But anyway **what is the difference between these two properties?**

Comment: Have you read remarks on msdn? *Do not use with nested types; use IsNestedPublic instead* for `IsPublic` is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 6):

The links you posted explain this:

[IsPublic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispublic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns

> true if the Type is declared public and is not a nested type;
>   otherwise, false.

[IsVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns

> true if the current Type is a public type or a public nested type such
>   that all the enclosing types are public; otherwise, false.

Comment: So the main difference seems to be the **nested types**.